# How can I disable Win10 ISS so I can Install XAMPP?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, iis

I'm an EE and not very familiar with the workings of websites and in particular with the Windows IIS server. Up until Windows 10 arrived I've never had any trouble installing development tools using the LAMPP, WAMPP, or XAMPP website installers. Tools such as Redmine, TestLink, CMS, and others. Now Windows 10 installs and activates IIS whether the user wants it or not. Consequently, it hogs port 80 which impacts installation connections to MySQL and other modules down the line. What used to be an easy install before Win10, has now become a mess of things tripping over the IIS installation.

Yesterday I downloaded a TiKi CMS to use as a collaboration website. I changed Apache to use Port 8080 instead of 80 as IIS is sitting on 80. That worked for Apache, except the Wiki install package couldn't find MySQL on Port 3306 or PHP. Aargh!

Does anyone know how to completely disabling the Win10 IIS server and all resources it is now hogging? I just want to set up the Tiki and get back to some circuit design work. What used to be so simple...

Comment: Have you tried to disable it in the services dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows menu, search for "Turn Windows features on or off".  Give it time to populate, then scroll down to find "Internet Information Services".  Uncheck it and click OK.  You may need to reboot to finish the process.

Please be aware that some software depends on IIS without it being obvious.  Fortunately, it's very easy to turn back on again, in the same window.